# Error al actualizar datos de un GridView con DropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un `GridView` en el cual traigo información desde la base de datos, y con ella también lleno los `DropDownList` pero al momento de querer editar los registros este falla y me dice que no se ha podido convertir de `DropDownList` a `String` o `Int`.

Este es el código con el que intenté hacer el `update`:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string myConnectionString = @"C:\\Users\\gutiece\\Desktop\\database\\" + "Database1.accdb";

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();

            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            int id = int.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            DropDownList tool = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool");
            DropDownList area = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool");
            DropDownList pool = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool");
            DropDownList team = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool");
            DropDownList station = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool");
            DropDownList operation = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool");
            DropDownList torque = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool");
            DropDownList tl = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool");

            command.CommandText = "UPDATE area SET tool_id = '" + tool + "', area = '" + area + "', pool = '" + pool + "', team = " + team + ", station = '" + station + "', operation = '" + operation + "', operation_torque = " + torque + ", tl_name = '" + tl + "' WHERE id =  = " + id + "";

            command.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = id;
            command.Parameters.Add("@TOOL_ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tool;
            command.Parameters.Add("@AREA", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = area;
            command.Parameters.Add("@POOL", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pool;
            command.Parameters.Add("@TEAM", OleDbType.Integer).Value = team;
            command.Parameters.Add("@STATION", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = station;
            command.Parameters.Add("@OPERATION", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = operation;
            command.Parameters.Add("@OPERATION_TORQUE", OleDbType.Integer).Value = torque;
            command.Parameters.Add("@TL_NAME", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tl;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            Response.Redirect("asignacion.aspx");
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

> Failed to convert parameter value from a DropDownList to a String.

Hice un `BreakPoint` y en cada valor, no entra nada solo aparece esto como valor de la variable `{System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList}`

Comment: Nota: **ASP.NET** es diferente de **ASP**

Answer (score 0):

A cada uno de los `DropDownList` debes acceder a la propiedad `SelectedValue`.

Ejemplo:

```
string tool = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool")).SelectedValue;
string area = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool")).SelectedValue;
string pool = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool")).SelectedValue;
string team = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool")).SelectedValue;
string station = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool")).SelectedValue;
string operation = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool")).SelectedValue;
string torque = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool")).SelectedValue;
string tl = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("gv_tool")).SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Como puedo convertir a entero? tambien lo he intentado y no lo he logrado

Comment: Convert.ToInt32() o Int32.Parse()

Comment: Lo hice de la seguiente manera `int team = Convert.ToInt32((DropDownList)row.FindControl("gv_tool"));` y me marco este error `command.Parameters.Aasdfdd("@AREA", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = area;`

Answer (score 0):

El problema se encuentra en esta línea:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE area SET tool_id = '" + tool + "', area = '" + area + "', pool = '" + pool + "', team = " + team + ", station = '" + station + "', operation = '" + operation + "', operation_torque = " + torque + ", tl_name = '" + tl + "' WHERE id =  = " + id + "";
```

Tomando como ejemplo la variable `tool` lo estás concatenando como si fuera un `string` cuando es del tipo `DropDownList`.

La solución consiste en armar la sentencia con parámetros:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE area SET tool_id = @TOOL_ID, area.....";
```

Para que posteriormente, indiques los valores que debes asignar a esos parámetros (puede ser con `SelectedValue` o `SelectedIndex` dependiendo del que desees guardar en la base de datos):

```
command.Parameters.Add("@TOOL_ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tool.SelectedIndex;
```

Y así con el resto de los parámetros.